# Why is this observation of NSTextField and NSNumberFormatter changing the behavior?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield, nsnotifications, nsnumberformatter

I have an `NSTextField`, with an `NSNumberFormatter` to restrict input to valid floating point. Because the user can type letters in the field, making it invalid (you get a beep and can't leave the field), I'd like to be notified when the field changes in any way, so I can disable other UI elements when the field is not valid.  I registered for a notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(myNotif:) 
    name:NSControlTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

But I see some strange behavior. If, in my notification callback, I ask for the double value.

```
- (void)myNotif:(NSNotification*)not {
    printf("  val = %f\n", _theTextField.doubleValue);
```

It alters the behavior of the text field. I can no longer type in a decimal point, among other things.

Anyone know why that is? What's going on and what's a good way to observe the field to know when it's valid and when it's not?

Comment: so you want the text field to only allow the user to enter **digits** and ONLY one decimal point, followed by two digits? eg. 12.00  ?  Or can the user enter only digits, and then you will in turn enter the floating point for them.

Comment: I don't care about the number of digits, but I want only floating point numbers greater than zero. Eg: "1", ".2", "12.31".

Comment: thats what im asking.. Do you want the restrictions to be done WHILE you type? or do you want validation to be done after the user finishes.

Comment: I want the restriction only when they finish, but I want to be able to *observe* whether it's valid or not, as they type.